# Network access in Android emulator

Tags: android, networking

I'm trying to reach internet through my Android app, but I both succeed and fail.

I start the emulator when I build my app, and the app is installed just fine. I can use the browser to access the internet, however, when I try this small code snippet ...

```
            InetAddress inet;
            try {
                inet = InetAddress.getByName("www.google.com");
                System.out.println ("IP  : " + inet.getHostAddress());
            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

... it all fails.

Is there any setting you must do to make the app reach the internet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must add this to your manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

to demand authorization to access internet from your app

Comment: And also outside the application-tag. You're an awesome human being, maid450! Thank you.

Comment: @Jim Carragher: If this answer solved your problem, you should mark this answer as Accepted.

Comment: @Deepak and Mudassir: I couldn't do it right away. Had to wait a couple of minutes.