# How to detect when WIFI is connected to internet?

Tags: android, networking, wifi

I am building an Android app and I use the code below to detect whether there is a network connection.  It works well and detects both mobile and WIFI networks.

My problem is how to detect an actual internet connection.  The code below returns true when connected to WIFI however the WIFI might not necessarily be connected to the Internet.

***The code***

```
    protected boolean checkInternetConnection() {     
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);  
    // test for connection     
    if (cm.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null             
            && cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable()             
            && cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected()) {

        return true;

        } 
    else {               
        return false;

        } 

} //end checkInterneConnection method
```

Thanks for your time.

Mel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to reach an internet adress. Therefor you should check the InetAdress class and the method isReachable: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/InetAddress.html#isReachable%28int%29

Comment: Thankyou for directing me to the InetAddress class. I ended up using the getByName() method as described in this post... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4602120/network-access-in-android-emulator

Answer (score 1):

This piece of code will check whether your device  Internet conecction,  If the signal is Poor it will show a Toast other wise not,

```
ConnectivityManager conMan = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo Info = conMan.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        if(Info == null){
            Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this,"Network Connection Failed! ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try ping http://google.com or doing something like this to confirm it's ok to visit internet.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
public boolean isConnectingToInternet(){
    ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) 
            m_context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
      if (connectivity != null) 
      {
          NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
          if (info != null) 
              for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++) 
                  if (info[i].getState() == 
                                      NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED)
                  {
                      return true;
                  }
      }
      return false;
}
```

And to check only wifi is simpler:

```
private boolean isWifiConnected() {
    int WIFI_STATE = wifi.getWifiState();
    if(WIFI_STATE == WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_ENABLED)
        return true;

    return false;
}
```

Comment: To just check if wifi is connected it would be better to use WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_ENABLED, especially if after checking you are going to try and use it for something.

Answer (score 0):

This code will really test the internet connection:

```
public static boolean isInternetAvailable() {
   try {
      InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName("google.com");
      return address.isReachable(2000); //This really tests if the ip, given by the url, is reachable 
      //return !address.equals(""); //This just tests if the IP is available but it could be taken in a previous request when internet was available
   } catch (Exception e) {
     Log.d("Internet check", "Unable to reach the url: "+url);
   }

   return false;
}
```